# Stencil JS - Only export one component from Component Library Project

Tags: stenciljs

I've searched a lot but I didn't find anything useful about this. I need to create a web-component with Stencil JS and I would like to split it in sub-components.
Is that possible doing this without exporting the whole component library, but instead exporting only the main component? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but the users will only download the components that are actually used on the page they're on thanks to Stencil's built-in lazy loader.